# When will the 2014 Moderator Election take place for UX.SE?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

So with the [2014 StackOverflow Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) in full swing, I was curious about when the next **UX.SE Moderator Election** will take place.  Are there any plans?  The last one I saw was in 2012?  Is that right?

I'd love to be a mod here and nominate myself when the time comes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've not had one since 2012, you're correct. That was pretty soon after we came out of beta status. However, elections on sites don't have set dates / times as to when they happen, they are brought about by site demand and / or by moderators requesting additional help with moderating.

At the moment there isn't really a need for extra moderators, although I'm sure that will change over time. Sites like ours are far smaller than the biggest SE sites such as StackOverflow or Superuser.com so the demands are far less for moderating. Another reason why we've not had an election since 2012 is that there are far more high rep users now than when we first graduated who are able to deal with a lot of the standard close-voting / deleting issues (plus the review queue feature has been enhanced to make all that far easier on everyone) leaving the moderators just to have the exceptions to deal with - spam (of which admittedly there has been an increase, but nothing too drastic just yet), trolling and the occasional HackerNews influx.

Now all this doesn't mean there won't be an election any time soon. We didn't grow much in 2013 as far as quantity of posts is concerned, but that's not been the case for the past few months - it's been steadily increasing for a while now so I wouldn't be surprised if there was a mod election later this year.

To be honest, that's probably a good thing for you if you wanted to be a moderator. Although you've amassed a pretty decent amount of rep since joining (I don't recall anyone getting so much rep in such a short time) you have only been a member here for 30-odd days. There may well be other users who've been here longer who would also want to stand, and your relatively new status might put you at a disadvantage there. (Although there is far more thought that goes into voting for people than their profile age (one would hope!)).

So, the best thing for you is to do is keep participating, keep reviewing and flagging where appropriate and make yourself indispensible to the site so that when the next election comes the rest of the users will see your nomination and vote you in because they know you can be trusted.

Have a look over some of the more recent election pages for other sites in the network to see the sort of nominations people put forward, compared to who actually ended up getting elected to get an idea of what the community look for in their mods. Look over the Nomination section to see what they promised, what people questioned about them and how they responded (if at all).

Recent elections:

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/4 (complete)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/3 (complete)

In Progress as of now:

- https://askubuntu.com/election
- https://stackoverflow.com/election/5

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer!

Comment: Doo doo doo doo! Doo doo doo doo! Twilight zone! A year later, it's here! http://elections.stackexchange.com/#ux.stackexchange!